# Получить данные с CoreData и отобразить их в TextField

Tags: ios, swift, coredata, swift4

Как отобразить данные сохраненные через `TextField` в CoreDate? Вот мой код сохранения:

```
@IBOutlet weak var subject: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var room: UITextField!
let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext


@IBAction func saveButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if subject?.text != "" && room?.text != ""{
        let newData = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "User", into: context)
        newData.setValue(self.subject!.text, forKey: "sub")
        newData.setValue(self.room!.text, forKey: "room")
    }
    do {
        try context.save()
        print("done")
    } catch {
        print("Failed saving")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
func fetchUser() -> [User]?
{
    var user: [User]? = nil

    do {
        user = try context.fetch(User.fetchRequest())
        return user
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not fetch request \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        return user
    }
}
```

получить данные:

```
var user: [User]? = nil

user = fetchUser()
```